# website for easy creating biblatex code?

Tags: biblatex, tools, online

Is there any website like http://www.citethisforme.com that easily creates citation file?

This website has a search engine, that the user can add his keywords like the name of author or book and when you find your desired result and click on it, the website's software adds that content's citation info into your preparing file. when the user added all his citations, he can adjust the format of citation and download a prepared copy of his references. The output is suitable to be used in word software.

Is there any website like this which the output file is a biblatex reference code prepared to be used in LaTeX documents?

P.S: I have found http://truben.no/latex/bibtex/ but this does not contain any search feature provided. The user has to fill the field one by one manually.

> **Conclusion:**
>
> Based on [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194963/52417) to
>   this question and my another visit to http://www.citethisforme.com
>   website; they have added an extra feature by which the user can export
>   all his citations list as a BibTeX file. Thanks to the developers of
>   the website and that they answered my question on this site.

Comment: For major publishers, JabRef has many search functionality

Comment: After some learning, writing the code yourself is faster than fixing ugly/inaccurate exports.

Comment: @Raphael: Agreed! though there can be advantages to having the database in a more flexible format. For example, if you also need to use your citations in an office word processor.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Definitely, but that thing need not be a web application

Comment: @Raphael I mentioned that website, because it was really user-friendly. I am using Zotero for reference management and citation, but that website and it's search feature was outstanding indeed, which I have never seen in any other software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer for [Cite This For Me](http://www.citethisforme.com) here (the site mentioned in the question).

BibTeX is now available on the site, it's in the Download menu as seen in this picture:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Once the additions go live, you could maybe add some usage examples to improve this answer. Thanks for contributing! :-)

Comment: @highace thanks, you did great. I think that bringing the `Download to Word` under that `Export` menu was a better idea than separating them in different menus.

Answer (score 11):

[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) does everything you describe, and you can export your library in `.bib` format. In my experience, you will have to go through and clean up the file afterward, but that's hard to avoid with bibliographies in any format.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) exports bibtex. One solution would be to search for the paper you want there and then export the record.

Comment: I think it does not work for citing books.

Comment: I think that it does. At any rate it has some books on it.

Comment: I have had some bad experiences with BibTeX from Google Scholar. It's probably advisable to check it.

Comment: IME the output from Google Scholar is almost unusable (especially for books). It's very incomplee.

Answer (score 4):

[Mendeley](http://mendeley.com/) also allows you to search for papers, store papers you find on major reference sites, and save as a `.bib` file.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the ['BibTeX entry from URL' Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibtex-entry-from-url/mgpmgkhhbjgkpnanlmlhibjfgpdpgjec/details) which adds a button to copy the BibTex for the currently open website to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

If these are papers with CrossRef DOIs, get them straight from CrossRef.

http://search.crossref.org

You can search, filter etc, to find the paper, and next to each result click 'actions' -> 'cite'. Citations in a variety of formats, including BibTeX

Alternatively, put the DOI straight into API to get the BibTeX:

```
http://api.crossref.org/works/10.5555/12345678/transform/application/x-bibtex
```

returns

```
@article{Carberry_2008,
    doi = {10.5555/12345678},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.5555/12345678},
    year = 2008,
    month = {aug},
    publisher = {{CrossRef}},
    volume = {5},
    number = {11},
    pages = {1--3},
    author = {Josiah Carberry},
    title = {Toward a Unified Theory of High-Energy Metaphysics: Silly String Theory},
    journal = {Journal of Psychoceramics}
}
```

Comment: Nice, but like so many of these services it "kills" accented characters (e.g. `ö` becomes `o`, which is quite a difference). Hence, one has to manually validate each and every entry!

Comment: Can you send any questions to labs@crossref.org, along with the DOI? It could be that the metadata isn't deposited by the publishers correctly, or that our API is mangling the accents.

Comment: @Joe Url field get some characters like `%2Fj` instead of a slash. Any ideas how to fix it?